# ¿Còmo hacer varios textbox dependiendo el numero seleccionado en un listbox?

Tags: php, html

Hice un pequeño codigo que no me funciona el cual quiero me genere una cantidad de label y textbox dependiendo el numero seleccionado en el listbox:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<p>Cantidad de Preguntas<br>

<select name="select">
    <option value=1 selected>1 Pregunta</option>
    <option value=2>2 Preguntas</option>
    <option value=3>3 Preguntas</option>
    <option value=4>4 Preguntas</option>
    <option value=5>5 Preguntas</option>
    <option value=6>6 Preguntas</option>
    <option value=7>7 Preguntas</option>
    <option value=8>8 Preguntas</option>
    <option value=9>9 Preguntas</option>
    <option value=10>10 Preguntas</option>
</select>
</p>

<body>
<h3>LLenar las Preguntas</h3>
<p>Formulario</p>
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<=value;$i++)
        echo "<p>Formulario</p>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver con MySQL y phpMyAdmin?

Comment: nada, buen aporte, pregunta editada

Comment: Al parecer necesitas usar AJAX para hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: se necesita ajax? Como seria eso?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo sin AJAX de la siguiente manera, primero carga en un div oculto las pregunas, lo puedes hacer con PHP por ejemplo y genera un HTML como el siguiente:

```
<div class="preguntas-disponibles" style="display: none;">
  <div class="pregunta disponible">¿Te gusta la sopa?</div>
  <div class="pregunta disponible">¿Te gusta la carne?</div>
  <div class="pregunta disponible">¿Te gusta la fruta?</div>
</div>
```

Lo he simplificado mucho para mejor entendimiento, si quieres añadir un textbox u otras cosas, solo tienes que modificar cada .pregunta con lo que quieras mostrar, por ejemplo:

```
<div class="pregunta disponible">
    <p>¿Te gusta la sopa?</p>
    <input type="textbox" name="pregunta1">
</div>
```

Ahora prepara el select y un contendor para las preguntas:

```
<h3>Cantidad de Preguntas</h3>
<select name="select">
    <option value=1 selected>1 Pregunta</option>
    <option value=2>2 Preguntas</option>
    <option value=3>3 Preguntas</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Generar preguntas</button>

<div class="preguntas"></div>
```

Nuevamente puedes crear las options en base al número de preguntas desde PHP, yo he preferido hacerlo a mano por comodidad.

También puedes crear el div de las preguntas dentro de un form para luego hacer el post, sería:

```
<form name="respuestas" action="evaluar.php">
    <div class="preguntas"></div>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Ahora en jQuery usa el siguiente código:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $(".preguntas-disponibles > .pregunta").addClass("disponible"); // Establecemos de nuevo las preguntas disponibles
    $(".preguntas > .pregunta").remove(); // Limpiamos las preguntas antiguas seleccioandas

    var cantidad = $("select").val();
    for(i = 1; i <= cantidad; i++) {
        e = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(".preguntas-disponibles > .pregunta.disponible").length);
        $(".preguntas").append($(".pregunta.disponible:eq(" + e + ")").clone());
        $(".pregunta.disponible:eq(" + e + ")").removeClass("disponible"); // Marcamos la pregunta como no disponible
    }
});
```

**NOTA:** *¡Cuidado! fíjate que el button se lanza con el selector button, por lo que si hay más de un button, por ejemplo, el del form, al pulsarlo también será llamado. Mejor usa un id o una clase para cada botón.*

Lo que hago es un bucle por las preguntas seleccionadas y por cada vuelta, genero un random según el número de preguntas diponibles para seleccionar una de ellas, la coloco en el div de las preguntas y la marco como no disponible quitando su clase para evitar duplicados.

Ejemplo funcional:

```js
$(".btn-generate").on("click", function() {
    $(".preguntas-disponibles > .pregunta").addClass("disponible"); // Establecemos de nuevo las preguntas disponibles
    $(".preguntas > .pregunta").remove(); // Limpiamos las preguntas antiguas seleccioandas

    var cantidad = $("select").val();
    for(i = 1; i <= cantidad; i++) {
        e = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(".preguntas-disponibles > .pregunta.disponible").length);
        $(".preguntas").append($(".pregunta.disponible:eq(" + e + ")").clone());
        $(".pregunta.disponible:eq(" + e + ")").removeClass("disponible"); // Marcamos la pregunta como no disponible
    }
    $("#enviar").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preguntas-disponibles" style="display: none;">
  <div class="pregunta">
    <p>¿Te gusta la sopa?</p>
    <input type="textbox" name="pregunta1">
  </div>
  <div class="pregunta">
    <p>¿Te gusta la carne?</p>
    <input type="textbox" name="pregunta2">
  </div>
  <div class="pregunta">
    <p>¿Te gusta la fruta?</p>
    <input type="textbox" name="pregunta3">
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Cantidad de Preguntas</h3>
<select name="select">
    <option value=1 selected>1 Pregunta</option>
    <option value=2>2 Preguntas</option>
    <option value=3>3 Preguntas</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-generate">Generar preguntas</button>

<form id="enviar" name="respuestas" action="evaluar.php" style="display: none;">
    <div class="preguntas"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-send">Enviar</button>
</form>
```